# How to get driver instance of newly opened tab in selenium webDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to coding. With my knowledge in have successfully logged in. In the home page, when I click on the specified link, it opens in the new tab which is expected behavior.
Now when I try to click on the elements which is present in the newly opened tab, I am getting no such element exception because the driver instance is pointing to the 1st tab and not the second tab.
How do I get the driver instance of newly opened tab.
Below is the code I am using.

//This is the base class.

```
public class BaseTest {
    public static WebDriver driver ;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("My url");

    }
}
```

//This is the login test.

```
public class LoginTest extends BaseTest {

    @Test
    public void login() throws InterruptedException {
        LoginPage loginpage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
                loginpage.enterUser_Name(userName);
                loginpage.enterPass_Word(passWord);
                loginpage.clickLoginButton();
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        loginpage.ClickOnTab();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        loginpage.clickOnLink(); //At this line, new tab is opened automatically.
        Thread.sleep(5000);
       }
}
```

//In newly opened tab, i need to click on some elements. This is the code I am using.

```
public class newTab extends BaseTest {

    @Test
    public void createNew()  {
        OtherPage create = PageFactory.initElements(driver,OtherPage.class);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        create.clickOnTab();// At this line I am getting no such element exception

    }
}
```

Please help me in how do i perform actions on newly opened tab and tell me where I am making mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below code

```
    public class LoginTest extends BaseTest {

    @Test
    public void login() throws InterruptedException {
        LoginPage loginpage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
                loginpage.enterUser_Name(userName);
                loginpage.enterPass_Word(passWord);
                loginpage.clickLoginButton();
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        loginpage.ClickOnTab();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        loginpage.clickOnLink(); //At this line, new tab is opened automatically.
        Thread.sleep(5000);
       }

     public String getLocalWindowHandle (){
        return driver.getWindowHandle();
     } 
}


public class newTab extends BaseTest {

    LoginTest loginTest = new LoginTest();

    @Test
    public void createNew()  {
        OtherPage create = PageFactory.initElements(driver,OtherPage.class);
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        ArrayList listOfAllWindowHandles = new ArrayList(driver.getWindowHandles());

        driver.switchTo().window((String) listOfAllWindowHandles.get(0));

        create.clickOnTab();
        driver.close();

        String firstWindowHandle = loginTest.getLocalWindowHandle();
        driver.switchTo().window(firstWindowHandle);


    }
}
```

Comment: Actually in my code I will be writing other classes similar to newTab class. For each class, should I write all these steps every time ? Is there any other and simple way to get the instance ?

Comment: @Raju the above code is solution for only New Tab. If in case u have to open new tab anywhere in ur automation cycle u will have to get the handle of the new window and work on it and then later close it and switch to original window.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just used the below two lines of code in loginTest class after clicking on the link. It worked.  "ArrayList<String> allTabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(allTabs.get(1));"

Comment: If u find the answer useful u can give the rating accordingly @Raju